# Adding a button event to close the form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I see a lot of questions similar to this, but nothing quite answers it.

I am wondering if there is an event that can be added to a button to directly fire the form_closing routine. I realize it is just one extra step to perform this using something like:

```
buttonOk.Click += new EventHandler(do_something);

private void do_something(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
}
```

but there are some instances where it would be an advantage to do something like:

```
buttonOk.Click += new EventHandler(form_close_event..);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda, to avoid creating a new named method, if what you want to do is sufficiently simple:

```
buttonOk.Click += (sender, args) => Close();
```

Comment: Exactly why this site is great for us newbies, you ask a question, and it exposes a new concept (lambda) to learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `anonymous method` ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)) for this, but in fact, it is all the same.

```
buttonOk.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... });
```

You can call whatever method from inside, so `this.Close()` is also okay.